# AcquireTokenSilent failed when using msal.js

Tags: reactjs, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, react-aad-msal

I'm using redirect flow to perform authenticate flow but sometimes after login redirect 
will met a canceled process when acquireTokenSilent

here is my login process

```
public async componentDidMount() {

    msalApp.handleRedirectCallback(error => {
      if (error) {
        const errorMessage = error.errorMessage ? error.errorMessage : "Unable to acquire access token.";
        // setState works as long as navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false
      }
    });

    if (!msalApp.getAccount()) {
      if (isMobile) {
        msalApp.loginRedirect(GRAPH_REQUESTS.CDA);
      }
      else {
        const response = await msalApp
          .loginPopup(GRAPH_REQUESTS.CDA)
          .catch(error => {
            ;
          });
        console.log("after login" + response);
        this.props.onFetchTemplate();
      }
    } else { this.props.onFetchTemplate(); }
  }
```

get access token function

```
export const getTokenRedirect = (): Promise<string> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        msalApp.acquireTokenSilent({
            scopes: [GRAPH_SCOPES.SITE_TEMPLATE]//,loginHint: JSON.parse((JSON.stringify(msalApp.getAccount(), null, 4))).name
        })
            .then(resp => resolve(resp.accessToken)).catch(error => {
                if (requiresInteraction(error.errorCode)) {
                    msalApp.acquireTokenRedirect(GRAPH_REQUESTS.CDA);
                }
            });
    });
};
```

and also my config

```
export const authRedirect = {
    clientId: "****",
    authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tennatid",
    validateAuthority: true,
    postLogoutRedirectUri: "https://myweburl",
    navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false
};

export const msalApp = new UserAgentApplication({
    auth: isMobile == true ? authRedirect : auth,
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE()
    },
    system: {
        navigateFrameWait: 0
    }
});
```

and this error happen,the authorize process when get token canceled by MS I think.I could not reproduce it in localhost.
[image]

Comment: It works well in local,and also login redirect works well,but when I tried to acquireTokenSilent When doing authorization, sometimes this step succeed and sometimes fail,just in the screenshot with no other logs.

Comment: What is the in the response of the red line item? The response data will show the reason

Comment: Sometimes a normal token is returned, but an error code is returned very frequently,`token_renewal_error`

Comment: Yes,regarding to this issue,I still do not solve it.Just do a redirect login when failed to get token to invoid this issue.@Nishant - MSFT Identity

Comment: why did you set navigateFrameWait to 0 ?
It could be causing this problem